@KafkaListener @Payload Validation in SpringBoot-3
I've used documented approach for payload validation in @KafkaListener and it worked perfectly fine in SpringBoot-2.7 and spring-kafka-2.8. But after upgrading to SpringBoot-3.2 and spring-kafka-3.1 the same code is no longer doing anything, and I'm not getting any exceptions thrown when event payload is invalid.
LocalValidatorFactoryBean is installed through KafkaListenerConfigurer like this:
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerConfigurer configureKafkaListeners(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
        return registrar -> registrar.setValidator(validator);
    }

The spring-boot-starter-validation dependency is present. But the validation isn't working and I'm not sure why.
Has anyone faced this issue and managed to make it work? Would appreciate any help.

Turned out that there was still javax.validation:validation-api on the path and I haven't replaced all import javax.* with import jakarta.*.
All is working as expected. I hope this helps someone to save time debugging this issue. :)
